# XR-2206 as a VCO for a synth

Tags: voltage, oscillator, synthesizer, vco

I was wondering if the XR-2206's pitch was controlled by It's Vcc or by it's RA? Im a little confused when it comes to how I would get the output from a keyboard(after it is changed to voltage) to change the pitch of the XR-2206.
Thanks!

Comment: Would be helpful to add some background to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You vary the current out of pin 7 or 8: -

[image]